# A problem in proving isomorphism classes of cores forming a lattice

Tags: graph-theory, lattice-orders, algebraic-graph-theory

I am reading the book "Algebraic Graph Theory" by Chris Godsil and Gordon Royle and I got confused with Lemma 6.3.3:

> The set of isomorphism classes of cores, partially ordered by "$\rightarrow$", is a lattice.

For which we need to prove that each pair of cores has a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound. To my understanding, I presume this means "upper class"$\rightarrow$"lower class". But the proof in the book seems reversing the meaning, i.e, "lower class"$\rightarrow$"upper class".

The following is the excerpt of proving the existence of least upper bound:

> We start with the least upper bound. Let $X,Y$ be cores. For any core $Z$, if $X\rightarrow Z$ and $Y\rightarrow Z$, then $X\cup Y\rightarrow Z$. Hence $(X\cup Y)^\bullet$ is the least upper bound of $X$ and $Y$.

To understand the problem better, we take $X=C_7, Y=C_5$, then $X\rightarrow Y$ and so $(X\cup Y)^\bullet=C_5=Y$. On the other hand, $Y\nrightarrow X$. So how come $(X\cup Y)^\bullet$ is an upper bound of $X$ and $Y$ if my understanding was correct?

**Note:** Given graphs $X,Y$, the notation $X\rightarrow Y$ means $X$ is homomorphic to $Y$. And the core of $X$ is denoted by $X^\bullet$, is a subgraph of $X$ such that $X^\bullet$ is a core and $X\rightarrow X^\bullet$.

Comment: Although I can't say much about the main question, let me just tell you that if $\leq$ is a partial ordering on a set, then so is $\geq$, where $a \geq b$ iff $b \leq a$. Moreover, $(X,\leq)$ is a lattice iff $(X,\geq)$ is. I think that this addresses one of your troubles.

Comment: I know what a homomorphism is, but I forget what "$X$ is homomorphic to $Y$" means. Does it mean that there is a homomorphism from $X$ to $Y$, or does it mean that there is a surjective homomorphism from $X$ to $Y$?

Comment: @bof Graph homomorphism is an adjacency-preserving map from $V(X)$ to $V(Y)$. It does not have to be injective or surjective.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, I know what the definition of a graph **homomorphism** is. What I was unsure of was the definition of "$X$ is **homomorphic** to $Y$". My guess now is that it means "there is a homomorphism from $X$ to $Y$".

Comment: @bof Yes, that is what it was supposed to be.